# Object added to array all change to last added object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm just simply addiing object to an array and all of them change to the last added value. This seems extremely strange.

```
    var _object = {x:0,y:0,z:0};
    var _objects = [];

    $("div").on("mousedown", function(e) {

        var offset = $(this).offset();

        _object.x = e.pageX-offset.left;
        _object.y = e.pageY-offset.top;

    }).on("mouseup", function(e) {

        var offset = $(this).offset();

        _object.z = 25;
        _objects.push(_object);

    });
```

[image: preview]

Is this happening because it's only adding a link of the object?

http://jsfiddle.net/u5wLn/

Comment: Objects are passed by reference in JS, you're updating and pushing the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help this was the perfect solution.

```
var _object = {x:0,y:0};
var _objects = [];

$("div").on("mousedown", function(e) {

    var offset = $(this).offset();

    _object.x = e.pageX-offset.left;
    _object.y = e.pageY-offset.top;

}).on("mouseup", function(e) {

    var offset = $(this).offset();

    _object.z = 25;
    _objects.push({
        x:_object.x,
        y:_object.y,
        y:25    
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use clone:

Change:

```
_objects.push(_object);
```

To

```
_objects.push( jQuery.extend(true, {}, _object) );
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are modifying the same object and adding the same object to the Array every time. To fix this problem, you can create new objects every time down is pressed, like this

```
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    _object = {x:0,y:0,z:0};         // We create a new object every time.
    _object.x = e.pageX-offset.left;
    _object.y = e.pageY-offset.top;
```

Check this [`Updated Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/u5wLn/1/)

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are changing the same instance of `_object` and pushing it to the array, every time you need to create a new object.

```
var _object, _objects = [];

$("div").on("mousedown", function (e) {

    var offset = $(this).offset();

    _object.x = e.pageX - offset.left;
    _object.y = e.pageY - offset.top;
    _objects.push(_object);

}).on("mouseup", function (e) {

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    _object.z = 25;
    _objects.push(_object);

}).mouseenter(function () {
    _object = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0
    };
});

$("button").on("click", function () {
    console.log(_objects);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7jWhx/)

Comment: that just added z and not x,y,z.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate a new object to push into the array.  There are many ways to do this, here's one:

```
   function coorObj(obj) {
       return {
           x: obj.x,
           y: obj.y,
           z: obj.z
       }
    }
```

Just call that in your `_objects.push(coorObj(_object));`

Here's your updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5wLn/3/)